# Google map in responsive map doesn't center map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google map. I  embeeded it into responsive web. Everything's fine, map behaves responsivly, but when I change the window size, for example open the page on a mobile phone, it just cuts from the map, when it's resizing, but I need it to center the map. I need the locations be still visible and I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help me? Hope my question is comprehensible. Thanks.

API call:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

JS code:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.652645, 21.083107);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

var beaches = [
    ['xxxx'],
    ['xxxx']
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var beach = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I can understand your question but where is your code?

Comment: Sorry. I have already edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `bounds` global variable.
2. Extend the bounds object when adding your markers.
3. On window resize, trigger a map resize and make the map fit the bounds object.

Global variable:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Extend the bounds in the `setMarkers` function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
}
```

Add this to your `initialize` function:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeUI);
```

Create a resize function:

```
function resizeUI() {

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Untested, but you get the idea...

Comment: thanks, very much. It still doesn't work, because console says that  map is not defined in resizeUI function.

Comment: Define `var map;` outside of your functions.